# Manwha about a human and demons generals

Tags: story-identification, manga

Im losing my mind right now because I'm trying to find a manwha but don't remember the name  and can't find anything online. From what i remember the plot is:  a human soldier accidentally kills a demon general so he is forced to  become the new general. I think he had white hair and the demons all like him even if he doesnt like them. Now the trick is that he thinks he's like the weakest person ever but he's actually crazy strong he just can't remember it (like a split personality) and he gets lucky (bending at the same time an assasin shoots at him). also he's connected to human king some how, I believe he was tortured which is why he can't remember being strong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Answer (score 1):

It matches [I'm not that kind of talent](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Deon_Hart).

- hero has white hair
- is strong, doesn't know it
- something wrong with him, like split personality (I didn't read till explanation)